# Issues cloning a Stripe platform customer to a Connected Account Customer - No such payment_intent: 'pi_abc...zyx'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I am using the React components for Stripe.js to try and process a payment for a connected account, and collect a fee off of each payment. I am not sure if the flow between my client and server is properly picking up my cloned customer and payment method. When my test customer tries to pay, I get "No such payment_intent: 'pi_abc...zyx'". I have ensured I am using the correct private test keys on both client and server. My Connected accounts are express accounts. When I go to my Stripe dashboard to look at the 'Customers' tab under 'Connect', this is what I see:

[image: Blank entries under the customer tab]

It looks like a blank entry is being created each time I make a payment attempt.

Here are the steps I am currently taking to let the platform customer pay a Connected account:

1. When a customer first signs up on my website, the Stripe-firebase extension I have installed automatically generates a customer ID. These are now considered my platform customers
2. I allow a platform customer to create an Express Connected account, this works perfectly fine. I now have their Stripe Account Id ex: 'acct_abc...xyz`.
3. Now here is the flow for when a platform customer tries to make a payment to a Connected Account:

**React/Client Side** - loadStripe with only the test key, not with a Stripe Connected account Id
`const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_abc...');`. I provide this to `<Elements stripe={stripePromise}>`

**React/Client Side** - User fills in payment form and presses submit. Create a paymentMethodReq from client/platform:

```
const paymentMethodReq = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: billingDetails
            });
```

**Node/Server Side** - Client then makes a request to my server to try and clone the platform payment method to a Connected account:

```
const serverPaymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
            customer: data.customerStripeId, // Customer ID of the customer paying (platform customer)
            payment_method: data.paymentMethodId, // Using the payment method Id generated from 'paymentMethodReq' on the client side
        }, {
            stripeAccount: connectedAccountStripeAccountId, // Using the Connected Account
        });
```

**Node/Server Side** - Client then makes a request to my server to create/"clone" a new customer from the platform and link it to the Connected account

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            payment_method: data.paymentMethodId, //Payment method id generated from 'serverPaymentMethod' above
        }, {
            stripeAccount: connectedAccountStripeAccountId, // Using the same Connected Account
        });
```

**Node/Server Side** - Client then makes a request to my server to create a payment intent with the customer id that was linked to the Connected account along with the payment method that was generated from the server

```
const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: data.price * 100,
        currency: 'usd',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        payment_method: data.paymentMethodId, // Payment method id generated from 'serverPaymentMethod' above
        customer: data.customerStripeId, // Customer Id generated from 'customer' above
        description: data.desc,
        capture_method: 'manual',
        application_fee_amount: (data.price * 100) * 0.15,

    }
```

**React/Client Side** - I try to confirm the card payment which results in the "No such payment_intent: 'pi_abc...zyx'" error

```
const confirmedCardPayment = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(paymentIntentResult?.data?.client_secret, {
                payment_method: serverPaymentMethod?.data.id //Payment method id generated from 'serverPaymentMethod' above
            });
```

I tried replacing `stripe.confirmCardPayment` on the client with a call to my server that instead confirms the payment intent like so:

```
const confirmPaymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
data.paymentIntentId, // Payment intent id generated from 'intent' above
{ 
payment_method: data.paymentMethodId // Payment method id generated from 'serverPaymentMethod' above
});
```

and this also results in "No such payment_intent 'pi_3K...9Rx'"

If anyone could help me figure out where I am going wrong in this process, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the PaymentIntent belongs to a different account with whose your current call is using a key of. It could be:

1. You created the PaymentIntent on Platform account, then confirm it
   from your Connected Account
2. You created the PaymentIntent on Connected Account, then confirm it
   from your Platform Account

While I am seeing both PaymentIntent creation and confirmation calls doesn't use the stripeAccount parameter, I suspect that you missed the code somewhere and the PaymentIntent was actually created in your Connected Account, lead to #2 possibility above.

To debug this you can check which account the PaymentIntent belongs to, by searching its ID on Dashboard's search box, or simply write to Stripe Support with the ID and they can check it for you.

Comment: So I added `stripeAccount: connectedStripeAccountId` option along with the payment method on the server-side when confirming the payment intent (both of which are happening with a connected account because I passed in the 'stripeAccount' option?) and it seemed to "work" on the client side. However, in the Stripe Dashboard, nothing shows up under customers for the Connected account, just another blank row like shown above. When I check the logs, I see `200 OK` so the intent seems to actually get confirmed and rightfully requires capture as the status. Not sure what else I am missing here